# Create a new project with pipenv in pycharm and copy all dependencies from a previous pipenv project

Tags: python, pycharm, pipenv

I have created a **project1** with **pipenv** using **Pycharm** and want to make a new one i.e. **project2**, and I want to have the same dependencies that were in project1.

**Python** version: 3.9,
**pipenv** version: 2020.11.15

As the project2 will have a separate **virtualenv** or **pipenv**(sorry if I am using the wrong terminology as I am new to Python) where all its dependencies will be installed.

I probably need to do something to pick the dependencies of project1 from its Pipfile but not sure how to do it exactly.

Any help in this regard would be appreciated.

Comment: check this module to clone one virtualenv/venv to another location `pip install virtual-clone`. The best way is to create a new virtual environment for the new project using `python3 -m venv name_of_venv`

Comment: I believe there must be a simple way to just copy all the dependencies from a pipfile of a previously created project to a new one.

Comment: Should be enough to copy `Pipfile` from project1 to project2, PyCharm should suggest installing dependencies after pipenv is created for project2

Comment: @user2235698 I tried copying my Pipfile from project1 to project2, but PyCharm didn't suggest anything..
Plus I also noticed that my PipFile does not contains all the libraries I have pip installed in my pipenv. 
`[[source]]
url = "https://pypi.org/simple"
verify_ssl = true
name = "pypi"

[packages]
requests = "*"
pyquery = "*"
robot = "*"

[dev-packages]

[requires]
python_version = "3.9"`

however, the directory C:\Users\myname\.virtualenvs\project1\Scripts      
contains all the libraries I have installed. Not sure why they are not being mentioed in Pip file.